# Dispatch event "keyup" is React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, keyboard-events, dispatchevent

I'm trying to dispatch the "keyup" event with a specific key - "Tab". The idea is that when set some value to input cursor automatically switch to the next input.
Is there a way how to do this?

I'm doing something like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-violet-ftr7l

Thanks for your answers)

Answer (score -1):

To switch between different input elements on `tab` you don't need event handler. Proper way is to set `tabIndex`. So when you press tab it will switch to next index.

```
export default function App() {
  const keyUpHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target.tabIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input tabIndex={1} onKeyUp={keyUpHandler} type="number" />
      <input tabIndex={2} onKeyUp={keyUpHandler} type="number" />
      <input tabIndex={3} onKeyUp={keyUpHandler} type="number" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this is completely not what OP is asking for. he wants to trigger tab when a certain number of characters is filled.

Comment: Thanks, that is right. I need to figure out how to trigger "keyup" event with a specific key only when another "keyup" event was fired

Comment: you cant really trigger key up in a graceful way. you should youse ref and focus.

Comment: Tried to do this with ref, same example, and still nothing. Do you have any ideas how to do this? I would be grateful))